# Update HTML title to contain access code

Tags: html, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set up OAuth2.0 for an iPhone app I'm working on.

I have "http://www.mywebsite.com/success" set up as my RedirectURI to which the service I am working with appends a response code and state. My response becomes "http://www.mywebsite.com/success?code=ftlZcvFZ3RACFqzgxHypJw637jObmAoHowSuyxeM&state=".

The example I am following has me trying to access this code by the following:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

Right now my page title is static and is always just Success, while the example expects it to include the code like: "Success ftlZcvFZ3RACFqzgxHypJw637jObmAoHowSuyxeM".

How do I modify my html to have the title reflect this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sever-side language PHP. It's easy to learn.

Comment: Send me a private message, if you have problems.